# How to wrap multiples of images in divs?

Tags: php, foreach

I am trying to wrap some divs round images using PHP to show a max of 8 images per div.
I am using custom fields WordPress plugin to pull out the images of the team but the need to wrap them in divs. I have it part working but it doesn't show a div for the remainder. I'm not sure if this is the best way but this is my code below.

```
function team($i,$t){                       

    $values = get_field('team_member'.$i);



if($values["url"]){

$answer = $i / 8;

    if(is_int($answer)){

        echo '<div class="team'.$i / 8.'">'. "\r\n";
        echo $t;
        $t  =   '';
        echo '</div>'. "\r\n";

    }                           

    $t .='<a href="'.$values["url"].'" alt="'.$values["alt"].' Thumbnail" >'. "\r\n";
    $t .='<img src="'.$values["sizes"]["thumbnail"].'" alt="'.$values["alt"].'" />'. "\r\n";
    $t .='</a>'. "\r\n";                                
    $i = $i+1;

    team($i,$t);
    }

}

team(1,'');
```

I am trying to get a result like below.

```
<div id="team">
    <div id="team1">
    <img 1>
    <img 2>
    ..
    <img 7>
    <img 8>
    </div>

    <div id="team2">
    <img 1>
    <img 2>
    ..
    <img 7>
    <img 8>
    </div>

    <div id="team3">
    <img 1>
    <img 2>
    ..
    <img 7>
    <img 8>
    </div>

    <div id="team4">
    <img 1>
    <img 2>
    <img 3>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why PHP and not jQuery?

Comment: I did try JQuery but couldn't get it to work in the way I wanted $('#team a').each(function(i){
          
  if(i % 8 === 0){
   
  $("<div id='tray" + (i/8) + "'></div>").prependTo('#team');
  
  $('#team a').slice(i, i + 8).appendTo('#tray' + (i/8));
  
  }
     
 });

Answer (score 1):

Your method is confusing and hard to read. Take a look at this example and go from there.

```
$images = array('bear.jpg','cat.jpg','owl.jpg','dog.jpg','bird.jpg');
$itemsPerDiv = 3;
$count = 0;
echo '<div class="animal-row">';

foreach($images as $img)
{
    if ($count % $itemsPerDiv == 0 && $count != 0)
    {
        echo '</div><div class="animal-row">';
    }

    echo '<img src="'.$img.'">';

    $count++;
}

echo '</div>';
```

This will output

```
<div class="animal-row">
    <img src="bear.jpg">
    <img src="cat.jpg">
    <img src="owl.jpg">
</div>
<div class="animal-row">
     <img src="dog.jpg">
     <img src="bird.jpg">
</div>
```

If you need an explanation on how this works let me know. I think your problem is your using the division operator and not MOD which is a lot more suitable in this case as it determines the remainder which you are missing out.